# Optimization of linear solving for small matrices (10x10)

Tags: optimization, open-source, 3d-modeling, augmented-reality, assembly

How to optimize the hell out of linear system solving for small matrices (10x10)? This would be used in an AR engine for a few games, but has to be done very fast.

This solver is to be executed in excess of 1 000 000 times in microseconds on an Intel CPU. I am talking to the extreme level of optimization used in graphiscs for computer games. No matter if I code it in assembly and architecture-specific, or study precision or reliability tradeoffs reductions and use floating point hacks (like many games, I use the -ffast-math compile flag, no problem). The solve can even fail for about 20% of the time!

Eigen's partialPivLu is the fastest in my current benchmark, outperforming LAPACK when optimized with -O3 and a good compiler. But now I am at the point of handcrafting a custom linear solver. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I will make my final solution open source and share it here.

Comment: Does https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl have anything useful for you in that effort?

Comment: @PatrickHughes: will try it and report back here. first experience with icc was not as fast as gcc with --ffast-math though

Comment: @PatrickHughes my tests with ICC produced code just as fast as code optimized with GCC, so I see no immediate use for MKL. Perhaps if I implement my own linear solve and try to optimize its operations, then MKL could help with the optimized components. Still, I'd avoid having such a dependency for this project.

Comment: You may be near the limit of what the hardware can do, too.  I remember one time we had an Intel field engineer in the office to consult on our 3D graphics processing for their integrated graphics chips, even with fully custom SIMD data massaging we got less than +5% from what we started with.  Best of luck with the optimizing!